# In CUDA, all threads of the same block share the same L1 cache?

Tags: caching, cuda

NVIDIA's doc for CUDA seems to suggest that shared memory and L1 cache use the same type of physical memory.

1. If that is the case, all threads within the same block share the same L1 cache since that is the case for shared memory?
2. L1 cache serve as cache to data in global memory?
3. Is this because a block is scheduled on a particular SM, and all warps running on the same SM share the same L1 cache?

Comment: See [CUDA C++ Programming Guide: Compute Capabilities: Compute Capability 5.x: Global Memory](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html?highlight=l1#global-memory-5-x) for which data in global memory is cached in L1. The section is about 5.x, but all later architectures just reference back to it, i.e. behavior hasn't changed since then.

Comment: The answer to all 3 questions is yes.

Comment: For some architectures you can even set how much memory is dedicated for L1 and how much for shared memory. However, even if 1.-3. is generally true, your premise that it is the same physical memory, not necessarily applies to all architectures.

Comment: Kepler and Pascal have physically separate shared memory and L1 (https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/pascal-tuning-guide/index.html). Pascal has 24KB of L1 per 2 SM Partitions (I am not 100% sure, the GP100 has 2 Partitions, the GP104 4 Partitions if I understand correctly). The shared memory is common to the whole SM (all 4 partitions).